# Implements Interface Angular 8

Tags: typescript, interface, angular8

I have two Interfaces User and Customer

```
export interface User {

   id?: number;
   name?: string;
   email?: string;
   password?: string;
   profile?: number;
   status?: number;

}
```

aand Customer Interface

```
import { User } from "../user";

export interface Customer extends User {

   user: User[];

   cnpj?: string;
   fantasy_name?: string;
   business_name?: string; 
   fixe?: Contact[];
   cel?: Contact[]; 

}
```

and in my component, how can I call this interfaces ?

```
method(customer: Customer) {
   customer.user.name = '';
   customer.user.email = '';
   customer.user.status= '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these interfaces with :

```js
let user: User = {
   id: 1;
   name: "John";
   ...
}
let customer: Customer = {
    user: { id: 1, ... },
    ...
}
```

Comment: inside Interface Customer the proprerty "let" in user show error

Comment: You have to declare it like any other variable. Updated answer